# Upgrade Redis 4.0.7 to 5.0.5

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I have environments of Redis varying from RHEL 6.10 to RHEL 7.7. I'm looking for information about supported platform and respective versions and other pre-requisites to get started. However I did not find any related documentation anywhere in Redis.io. Could anyone please provide information on this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine, there is no external dependencies.

See the last paragraph of https://redis.io/topics/introduction

Comment: Thanks Leo. Would Redis Enterprise work differently as compared to opensource version. I intend to install opensource redis but I came across this document https://docs.redislabs.com/5.2/rs/release-notes/release-notes-redis-enterprise-software-v5-0-2/

and under the section "Other" I see it is supported on RHEL 7.5.

Comment: Redis Enterprise has additional features plus support, so there you want to check [Supported Platforms](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/administering/designing-production/supported-platforms/).